# VBA - 'For' Loop Optimization using dictionary

Tags: excel, vba, dictionary, for-loop, if-statement

Originally, I had code that used the data filter across the header, and cycled through each criteria in a specific row, copying+pasting all the visible data on that sheet to various corresponding sheets. I felt that this was too rudimentary, and with some help on SO, wrote new code as seen below. For a reason I am not sure of, my macro now hangs for 5-10 minutes to process the data. Compared to the data filter method, which took about 10-15 sec.  Typically my worksheet is less than 1000 rows. But let's just say, absolute worst case, it's no more than 2000 rows.

Each row contains about 50 consecutive cells of text some of which have their interior filled by a color and about 10 of the 50 have EXACT or simple SUM formulas.

If anyone has any pointers as what I should change that could speed it up, that would be great! Or if you think the data filter method is best.

```
Const TERR As String = "NA,AU,BR,CAen,CAfr,DE,ES,FR,IT,MX,USA,UK"

Sub CATsplit(wb2)
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

Dim wbMacro As ThisWorkbook
Dim dict As New Scripting.Dictionary
Dim t As Variant
Dim newSheet As Worksheet
Dim LC As Long


LC = Sheets(1).Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column



       For Each t In Split(TERR, ",")
        ' Create each sheet
          Set newSheet = Sheets.Add(after:=ActiveSheet)
              newSheet.Name = t
       With newSheet
            dict.Add t, .Cells(.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
       End With
       Next

Sheets("NA").Name = "No Result"
Sheet(1).Activate

For r = 2 To LR Step 1


 If Application.WorksheetFunction.IsNA(Sheets(1).Range("K" & r)) Then
        Range(Cells(r, 1), Cells(r, LC)).Copy Destination:=Sheets("No Result").Cells(dict("NA") + 1, 1)
        dict("NA") = Sheets("NA").Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
        GoTo Nxt

 End If


 If Sheets(1).Range(Cells(r, 14)).Value = "Australia" Then

        Range(Cells(r, 1), Cells(r, LC)).Copy Destination:=Sheets("AU").Cells(dict("AU") + 1, 1)
        dict("AU") = Sheets("AU").Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
        GoTo Nxt
    End If


If Sheets(1).Range(Cells(r, 14)).Value = "Brazil" Then

        Range(Cells(r, 1), Cells(r, LC)).Copy Destination:=Sheets("BR").Cells(dict("BR") + 1, 1)
        dict("BR") = Sheets("BR").Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
        GoTo Nxt
    End If
 ''''  9 other IF statements structured the same way

Nxt:

Next r
```

Comment: Isn't LC getting its value from the first worksheet in the new workbook? Qualify your worksheets' parent workbook.

Comment: Put [Option Explicit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xyVrl.gif) above `Const TERR As String = ...` and rerun your code.

Comment: @Jeeped - I was trying to post only relevant parts of my code. Copied the wrong bits over to this post. Edited to simplify

Comment: Something's wrong with your code listing, looks like there should be a `With ... End With` of some kind around the first indented section?

Comment: Also right. Sorry. Should have just pasted everything.

Comment: You probably need to turn off Automatic Recalculations.  Copying long ranges between sheets can trigger a lot of recalcs, and these can be especially slow if its a big workbook with lots of formulas.

Comment: `Sheet(1)` do you mean `Sheets(1)`  ?

Comment: `Sheets("No Result")` or `Sheets("NA")` ?  It's hard to imagine this runs at all, let alone slowly.

Comment: @Tim - had to change the name of that Sheet for confidentiality

Comment: I'm not seeing what benefit you're getting from the dictionary here?  It holds the current row for each sheet, but you're still performing the `.End(xlUp).Row` instead of just adding one to the dictionary value, so there's no advance over using `.End(xlUp).Row+1` when performing the copy?

Comment: @TimWilliams That makes sense. This was my first time using a dictionary. Didn't think of amending other code the reflect that.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a different approach.  It uses a mapping object to store the sheetname and row number in the dictionary.

```
Option Explicit

Sub CATsplit()

    Dim dict As New Scripting.Dictionary
    Dim LC As Long, LR As Long, r As Long, k
    Dim v

    dict.Add "NA", GetTerritory("No result", 2)
    dict.Add "AU", GetTerritory("Australia", 2)
    dict.Add "BR", GetTerritory("Brazil", 2)
    '...etc

    With ThisWorkbook
        For Each k In dict.keys
            .Sheets.Add(after:=.Sheets(.Sheets.Count)).Name = dict(k).sheetName
        Next k
    End With

    With Sheets(1)

        LC = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        LR = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

        For r = 2 To LR

            v = .Cells(r, 14).Value
            If Application.IsNA(.Cells(r, 11)) Then v = "NA"

            If dict.Exists(v) Then 'have a sheet for this row?
                .Cells(r, 1).Resize(1, LC).Copy _
                  ThisWorkbook.Sheets(dict(v).sheetName).Cells(dict(v).rowNum, 1)
                dict(v).rowNum = dict(v).rowNum + 1
            End If

        Next r
    End With

End Sub
```

"Factory" function:

```
Function GetTerritory(sheetName As String, rowNum As Long) As Territory
    Dim rv As New Territory
    rv.sheetName = sheetName
    rv.rowNum = rowNum
    Set GetTerritory = rv
End Function
```

Class module "Territory":

```
Public sheetName As String
Public rowNum As Long
```

For clarity I've left out the code to disable screenupdating/calculation, but you should probably add that.

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to venture into using dictionaries, I offer for your consideration jumping in with both feet and building dictionaries that contain dictionaries. I believe you should see a greatly improved performance with this technique.

Admittedly, this technique is long. It is possible to create dynamically generated multi level dictionaries whenever a new value appears (in this case it would be a new country), however, that requires building a Class Module which goes beyond what is requested here.

```
Sub CATsplit()
Dim dnyRegion As New Scripting.Dictionary
Dim dnyOutput As New Scripting.Dictionary

Dim dnyAU As New Scripting.Dictionary
dnyRegion("Australia") = "AU"
dnyOutput.Add "AU", dnyAU

Dim dnyBR As New Scripting.Dictionary
dnyRegion("Brazil") = "BR"
dnyOutput.Add "BR", dnyBR

Dim dnyCAen As New Scripting.Dictionary
dnyRegion("Canada-English") = "CAen"
dnyOutput.Add "CAen", dnyCAen

Dim dnyCAfr As New Scripting.Dictionary
dnyRegion("Canada-French") = "CAfr"
dnyOutput.Add "CAfr", dnyCAfr

Dim dnyDE As New Scripting.Dictionary
dnyRegion("Denmark") = "DE"
dnyOutput.Add "DE", dnyDE

Dim dnyES As New Scripting.Dictionary
dnyRegion("Estonia") = "ES"
dnyOutput.Add "ES", dnyES

Dim dnyFR As New Scripting.Dictionary
dnyRegion("France") = "FR"
dnyOutput.Add "FR", dnyFR

Dim dnyIT As New Scripting.Dictionary
dnyRegion("Italy") = "IT"
dnyOutput.Add "IT", dnyIT

Dim dnyMX As New Scripting.Dictionary
dnyRegion("Mexico") = "MX"
dnyOutput.Add "MX", dnyMX

Dim dnyUK As New Scripting.Dictionary
dnyRegion("United Kingdom") = "UK"
dnyOutput.Add "UK", dnyUK

Dim dnyUSA As New Scripting.Dictionary
dnyRegion("United States") = "USA"
dnyOutput.Add "USA", dnyUSA

Dim dnyNA As New Scripting.Dictionary
'This will pick up everything else
dnyOutput.Add "NA", dnyNA

'This section sorts all of the data into the appropriate sub-dictionary.
Dim arrRow As Variant, strRegion As String, i0 As Long
With ActiveSheet
    For i0 = 1 To .UsedRange.Rows.Count
        strRegion = .Cells(i0, 14).Value
        If dnyRegion.Exists(strRegion) Then
            strRegion = dnyRegion(strRegion)
        Else
            strRegion = "NA"
        End If

        arrRow = .Range(.Cells(i0, 1), .Cells(i0, .UsedRange.Columns.Count)).Value
        dnyOutput(strRegion).Add dnyOutput(strRegion).Count + 1, arrRow
    Next i0
End With

'This section creates the appropriate tabs and dumps the data.
Dim eaRegion As Variant, eaRow As Variant, Dest As Range
For Each eaRegion In dnyOutput.Keys
    If dnyOutput(eaRegion).Count > 0 Then
        ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Add After:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)
        With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)
            .Name = eaRegion
            For i0 = 1 To dnyOutput(eaRegion).Count
                Set Dest = .Cells(i0, 1)
                Dest.Resize(1, UBound(dnyOutput(eaRegion)(i0), 2)).Value = dnyOutput(eaRegion)(i0)
            Next i0
        End With
    End If
Next eaRegion
End Sub
```